# Rename files with filename lengths longer than 143 characters on synology nas

Tags: bash

I am trying to encrypt a folder on our Synology Nas but have found roughly 250 files with filenames longer than 143 characters. Is there any command I can use to remove all characters from the end of the file names so it is under 143 characters in length.

The command i used to find the files

```bash
find . -type f -name '???????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????*'
```

I was hoping to be able to navigate to the 8-9 or so directories that hold these chunks of files and be able to run a line of code that found the files with names longer than *n* characters and drop the extra characters to get it under 143.

Comment: What should happen if two files in the same directory have the same 143 character prefix?

Comment: Good question, if two files have the same character prefix we could drop one of them by 1 more character. Or append a 1 or 2 to the end. Duplicates could be done manually if they are discovered as i think a majority would be unique.

Comment: The trivial and obvious solution simply loses one of the files if there are two with the same prefix. If that's acceptable, just do that: `mv` each match to the truncated name.

Comment: Thanks triplee, if i understand you, youre saying pipe the command into a mv command? what mv command would match each to the truncated name?

Comment: Do these files have extensions (e.g. `.txt`), and should they be retained?

Comment: They do have extensions that should be retained.

Comment: Okay, https://ideone.com/aXudZS should work fine everywhere, but too ugly to post as an answer.

Comment: @oguzismail : What is the purpose of the _sh {} +_ at the end of your solution? The `{} +` is replaced by the filenames, so we have after the -exec basically `sh -c 'your script' sh FILENAME1 FILENAME2 ...`. I feel that this second _sh_ should be removed (though it does not harm here).

Comment: @user1934428 If we removed sh, then FILENAME1 wouldn't be processed. The first argument after the command string is assigned to $0; for arg; do ... starts from $1. Compare `sh -c 'for x; do echo $x; done' 1 2 3 4` to `sh -c 'for x; do echo $x; done' sh 1 2 3 4`

Comment: @oguzismail thank for your solution i will turn that into a script and see how it goes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Synology, but if you have a `rename` command which accepts Perl regex substitutions, and you are fine with assuming that no two files in the same directory have the same 143-character prefix (or losing one of them in this case is acceptable), I guess something like

```sh
find . -type f -regex '.*/[^/]\{143\}[^/]+' -exec rename 's%([^/]{143})[^/]+$%$1%' {} +
```

If you don't have this version of the nonstandard `rename` command, the simplest solution might be to pipe `find`'s output to Perl and then pipe that to `sh`:

```sh
find . -type f -regex '.*/[^/]\{143\}[^/]+' |
perl -pe 's%(.*/)([^/]{143})([^/]+)$%mv "$1$2$3" "$1$2"' |
sh
```

If you don't have access to Perl, the same script could be refactored into a `sed` command, though the regex will be slightly different because they speak different dialects.

```sh
find . -type f -regex '.*/[^/]\{143\}[^/]+' |
sed 's%\(.*/\)\([^/]\{143\}\)\([^/]\+\)$%mv "\1\2\3" "\1\2"' |
sh
```

This has some naïve assumptions about your file names - if they could contain newlines or double quotes, you need something sturdier (see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020). In rough terms, maybe try

```sh
find . -type f -regex '.*/[^/]\{143\}[^/]+' -exec bash -c 'for f; do
    g=${f##*/}
    mv -- "$f" "${f%/*}/${g:0:143}"
  done' _ {} +
```

Comment: Thanks triplee, sadly the rename command does not work but i will try to pipe to perl and then sh and see if that works! ** unfortunately the perl command is also not found, thank you for your help though, it is much appreciated.

Comment: Put `echo mv` instead of `mv` so you can see what it's doing, or omit the pipe to `sh` until you see that it's doing what you hope. The `-regex` argument to `find` might not be entirely portable here (and it sucks that it uses a different dialect for braces than Perl).

Comment: The requirement to retain the extension which was only communicated in comments is not hard to add, but you should really ask a new question if you have additional requirements and already received answers which solved what you actually asked.

Comment: This sadly did not solve the problem as synology did not recognise the perl command, but ill mark it as solved because this would work on a normal unix OS.

Comment: You could refactor it to use `sed` instead. See update now.